# Trekstor Surfbook w1 Wifi not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, netbook

So, I bought this Netbook yesterday. It came with win 10 but I wanted to install Elementary OS on it. It ended up not working and wasting 7 hours of my time trying to intall it. Then I installed Win 10 32 bit back on it ( procesor is x64 but the uefi is 32bit). I downloaded the drivers from the support website of the manufacturer, most of them worked out fine beside the wifi driver. I searched the web and tried out different drivers. Then I found out that the Chuwi driver works (the folder it was it was called v200, it's a x86 wireless adapter driver), but not fully. The wifi icon has a cross on it like this

[image: That's the red cross I was talking about.]

and does not scan for wifi networks. I am desperate for help. I need to travel in 2 days and I can't seem to find any help nowhere.

The device manager looks just fine:

[image: The device manager looks just fine]

Answer (score 0):

The Wi-Fi adapter for this netbook is WLAN 802.11 b/g/n (2.4 GHz only) + Bluetooth 4.0.  Do you have any 2.4GHz AP's enabled in your area?  Or is your Access Point setup for 5GHz only - If that's the case, your wireless adapter will not see any networks because it cannot see 5GHz networks with a 2.4GHz only card.

Comment: Sorry for the slow.. very slow response. The laptop worked with my home WIFI out of the box. I tried to install a linux distro on it and that made me lose the windows drivers that were preinstalled. I reinstalled them from the website but that did not help. The Bluetooth worked just fine but the WIFI still showed no signs of life.
I bought a usb WIFI dongle and it works now, still I would like to have it working withouth the dongle, I just cant find the right drivers.